# YouTube Api 3 upload and view videos with single user

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api

I need to allow users to upload videos to my youtube account from my .net web app. I want all views to come through my web site so I can control who can view them and when based on their role in my web app. Really what I want is to do something like this for the upload and play back:

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings  = new YouTubeRequestSettings("Appliactionname", "Developer key" "Username", "Password");
YouTubeRequest request  = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
Video newVideo = new Video();
```

But that code is for V2.0 and has been deprecated in V3.0. Is there any way to do this in V3.0?

I don't want the users to have to log in with their own account. I want one account behind the scenes that does everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, the answer would be a service account, but that is not supported for the YouTube API https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5370. The work around which isn't really what I want, but I think is going to get me as close to what I want as possible with the current API is to set it up as an Installed Application with offline access and refresh tokens. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth